# How to evaluate struts 2 s:if?

Tags: struts2

i have an object called 'item'.
it has a property called 'type'

when i do this:

```
<s:property value="item.type" />
```

i get this:
Q

ok, so i can read the value, but when i try this:

```
<s:property value="item.type == 'Q'" />
```

i get an empty string

this give me an empty string:

```
<s:property value="%{#item.type == 'Q'}" />
```

i even tried this:

```
<s:property value="item.type.equals('Q')" />
```

but i got this string:
false

how do i get 'true'?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ok, i struggled with this for ever... and eventually found out how to do this.  "Q" is a string literal versus 'Q' which is a character.  therefore...

```
<s:if test="%{#item.type == 'Q'}">
```

will always evaluate to false.  instead try...

```
<s:if test="%{#item.type == \"Q\"}">
```

i've also seen it done this way...

```
<s:if test='%{#item.type == ("Q")}'>
```

(notice the single quotes around the test attribute value.)

OGNL is a thorn in my side.  i'm guessing the OP has already figured this out.  but hopefully this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can put any EL inside the value property of this tag.  You could accomplish that with something like:

```
<s:if test="%{#item.type == 'Q'}">
  true
</s:if>
<s:else>
  false
</s:else>
```

More examples of this are [here](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts2controltags/if-else.shtml)

Note - I use freemarker for the view, so the above may not be exact.  In freemarker you could do this with an assign:

```
<#assign val = (item.type == 'Q')/>
${val}
```

Or, you could also use the if construct like above:

```
<#if (item.type == 'Q')>true<#else>false</#if>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:set name="prop" value="%{'val'}"/>

<s:if test="%{#prop == 'val'}">
  <s:property value="%{#prop}" />
</s:if>

<s:elseif test="%{#prop=='val1'}">
  <s:property value="%{#prop}" />
</s:elseif>

<s:else>
  ...
</s:else>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as:

```
<s:property value='item.type == "Q"' />
```

Just need to replace single quotes with double quotes and vice-versa